# How to write a recursive function using levels depth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my function:

```
 public static function f($rows)
       {
           $str = '<ul>';
           $level = 1;
           foreach($rows as $row)
           {
               if($row['section_level'] > $level)
               {
                   $level = $row['section_level'];
                   // here I want to call this function again for recursion, but how??
               }
               else
               {
                   $str .= '<li><a href="#">'.$row['username'].'</a></li>';
               }
           }
           $str .= '</ul>';
           return $str;
       }
```

my array:

```
array (

   array(

     ['name'] => 'test1',
     ['level'] => 1

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test2',
     ['level'] => 2

   },

   array(

     ['name'] => 'test3',
     ['level'] => 2

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test4',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test5',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test6',
     ['level'] => 3

   },
   array(

     ['name'] => 'test7',
     ['level'] => 3

   },



)
```

can you please help me complete my function to render that array by levels, adding to each level a `<ul>`, thus something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <a href="#">level1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#">level1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">level2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's keeping you from just using a nested loop? Recursion is dangerous territory.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as JavaScript, CSS and MySQL?

Comment: how to use a nested loop in this case?, please any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea for Recursion is for build up a data structure tree.

Therefore, depth is not important, parent - child relationship is essential.

That means in you array, you need at least have two value in one array element, example:

```
[ 'id' => 1, 'parent' => null ],
[ 'id' => 2, 'parent' => 1 ],
[ 'id' => 3, 'parent' => 1 ],
[ 'id' => 4, 'parent' => 2 ],
....
```

Once you have your data array, you can use http://hezachary.wordpress.com/2008/07/19/%E6%95%B0%E7%BB%84%E5%AD%90%E7%88%B6%E7%BA%A7%E9%80%92%E5%BD%92%EF%BC%8C%E6%A0%91%E7%8A%B6%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90/
to run your array, and get a structured array.

then you can use function Recursion to export html, such as:

```
function display( $ary ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ary as $data){
        echo '<li>';
        echo $data['html'];
        if( sizeof( $data['node'] ) ){
            display( $ary );
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Here is the solution for nest strucutre, which I do not like at all:

```
function f($rows)
{
    $str = '';
    $level = 0;
    $first_li_mode = true;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($level > $row['level']) {
            $str .= '</li></ul>' . "\n";
            $str .= '</li><li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
            $first_li_mode = true;
        } elseif ($row['level'] > $level) {
            $str .= '<ul><li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
            $first_li_mode = false;
            ;
        } else {
            if (!$first_li_mode) {
                $str .= '</li>' . "\n";
            } else {
                $first_li_mode = false;
            }
            $str .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
        }

        $level = $row['level'];
    }
    while ($level > 0) {
        $str .= '</li></ul>' . "\n";
        $level--;
    }
    return $str;
}


$qrr = array(
    array('name' => 'test1', 'level' => 1),
    array('name' => 'test2', 'level' => 2),
    array('name' => 'test3', 'level' => 2),
    array('name' => 'test4', 'level' => 3),
    array('name' => 'test5', 'level' => 3),
    array('name' => 'test6', 'level' => 3),
    array('name' => 'test7', 'level' => 3),
    array('name' => 'test8', 'level' => 2),
    array('name' => 'test9', 'level' => 1),
);

echo f($qrr);
```

Comment: I'am using nested sets model, I have lft and rgt properties

Comment: It is a bad choice, far as I see.

Comment: The function from my link only work with [parent - child relationship], not nest

Comment: Please check my code above, you just need change few lines for your project, but still, nest is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just try nested loop

```
<?php 
function f($rows)
       {
           $str = '';
           $level = 1;
        $i=1;
           foreach($rows as $row)
           { 

         $str .="<ul><li>".$i;


            $str .="<ul><li>".$row['name']."</li><li>".$row['level']."</li></ul>";                   

              $str .="</li></ul>";$i++;
           }
           $str .= '</ul>';
           return $str;
       }

$qrr=array(

   array(
    'name' => 'test1',
     'level' => 1
   ),
   array(

     'name' => 'test2',
     'level'=> 2
   ),

   array(

     'name' => 'test3',
     'level' => 2

   ),
   array(

     'name' => 'test4',
     'level'=> 3

  ),
   array(

     'name' => 'test5',
     'level' => 3

   ),
   array(

     'name' => 'test6',
     'level'=> 3

   ),
   array(

     'name' => 'test7',
     'level' => 3

   ),



);

echo f($qrr);
?>
```

Comment: Is that possible to make the <ul> put inside <li> depending of the level?, not just appending one above other

Comment: Have to try this code? you can use nested list with nested loop. I don't know this is your need. Anyway just try.

Comment: yes ' ive tried it, it renders one above other by level

Comment: Then you can use your logic. Because you are a programmer you have to code for your logic. Happy to coding.